# Replace " " character derived column SSIS

Tags: ssis

So I am getting CSV Files and for some reason they are coming as "123-45-9873".

Now I trim the "-" out but the column is an SSN column so I am left with "12345987 taking the 3 out and putting the " character on the table.

What replace function can I use to replace the very character?

For reference, this is what I am doing

```
(DT_STR,9,1252)REPLACE(SSN,"-","")
```

and getting "12345678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the quote (") character is considered a part of the input string.

There is two options:
1. correct you flat file source to define quotation characters for this field, so it will remove " values from the beginning and end of the string.
2. Use another replace to get rid of quotes.REPLACE(REPLACE(SSN,"\"",""),"-","")